# Given a Gaussian Likelihood, and a Normal-Wishart prior, what is the posterior?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

Given a Gaussian Likelihood : $$P(Y|\mu,\Lambda) = \prod_{t=1}^T P(y_t|\mu,\Lambda)$$

and a Normal-Wishart Prior: $$P(\Lambda) = Wishart(\Lambda|v_0,W_0)$$

what is the posterior distribution?

Comment: Related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153241/derivation-of-normal-wishart-posterior; also see page 18 here as well: https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You know that

$$
f(\Lambda) = \frac{|\Lambda|^{\frac{\nu_0 - p - 1}{2}} exp(-\frac{1}{2}tr(W_0 \Lambda))}{2^{\nu_0 p /2} |W_0|^{-\nu/2} \Gamma_p (\nu_0/2)}
$$

where $\Lambda, W_0$ : positive-definite. (Parameterization can yield somewhat different PDF, but that does not matter) Thus,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Lambda | \mathbf{y}_T &\propto \prod_i^T |2\pi \Lambda^{-1}|^{-1/2} exp(-\frac{1}{2}(y_i - \mu)' \Lambda^{-1} (y_i - \mu)) \times |\Lambda|^{\frac{\nu_0 - p - 1}{2}} exp(-\frac{1}{2}tr(W_0 \Lambda)) \\[10pt]
&\propto |\Lambda|^{\frac{n+\nu_0 - p - 1}{2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}tr(nS\Lambda + W_0 \Lambda)\right) \\[10pt]
&\sim Wishart(\nu_0 + n, W_0 + nS)
\end{aligned}
$$

where $S = \frac{1}{n} \sum (y_i - \mu)'(y_i - \mu)$